# Team Making using Python?

Tags: python, sorting, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I am running a tournament for 16 people, and each tournament, every person earns a certain number of points. These points are earned from 8 different games.

I need to make four teams of four, and their averages and standard deviations should ideally be as close together as possible (to make the fairest teams). I have already done this using a binpacking library. However, I have read that the knapsack problem is often better than binpacking at picking teams.

Ideally, I would be able to select one of the 8 games to balance points off of and obtain fair teams from that; right now I am just using overall points.

If anybody knows of any libraries or functions I can borrow to complete this task, please let me know. Additionally, if there are ways I can further optimize my code, please tell– I am still a beginner. My code is below.

````
import numpy as np

levels = np.genfromtxt('points.txt', dtype = 'float')
players = np.genfromtxt('players.txt', dtype = 'str')
playerLevels = zip(players, levels)
playerLevelsList = list(playerLevels)

averageLevels = sum(levels)/len(levels)
print('Average points are', averageLevels)

bins = binpacking.to_constant_bin_number(playerLevelsList, 4, 1)

a, b, c, d = [ [individualArray] for individualArray in bins]

a = a[0]
b = b[0]
c = c[0]
d = d[0]
a1 = a[1]
b1 = b[1]
c1 = c[1]
d1 = d[1]

team1 = list(zip(*a))
team2 = list(zip(*b))
team3 = list(zip(*c))
team4 = list(zip(*d))

points1 = sum(team1[1])/4
points2 = sum(team2[1])/4
points3 = sum(team3[1])/4
points4 = sum(team4[1])/4

stdev1 = np.std(team1[1])
stdev2 = np.std(team2[1])
stdev3 = np.std(team3[1])
stdev4 = np.std(team4[1])

print('Team 1 is', team1[0])
print('Team 2 is', team2[0])
print('Team 3 is', team3[0])
print('Team 4 is', team4[0])
print('\n-----Stats-----')
print('Team 1 Average is', points1, 'with a standard deviation of', stdev1)
print('Team 2 Average is', points2, 'with a standard deviation of', stdev2)
print('Team 3 Average is', points3, 'with a standard deviation of', stdev3)
print('Team 4 Average is', points4, 'with a standard deviation of', stdev4)```
````

Answer (score 1):

This may be a start to your answer.  This was interesting and I had some time to kill.  I was curious just how many unique team combinations are possible.  Using an online combinations and permutations calculator I found out there are only 1820 unique teams possible when selecting 4 from 16 when order is not important.  Using Python I generated a list of possible unique teams.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it

team_score_total=[]

teams = []
players=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

for i in it.combinations(players, 4):
    teams.append(list(i))

# only 1,820 unique team possibilities
print(len(teams))

#check if there are duplicate players before adding to league
def CanAddTeamLeague(team, league):
    for t in league:
        for i in t:
            if i in team:
                return False
    return True;

#check if there are duplicate leagues before adding to list
def CanAddLeagueToList(league, league_list):
    for lg_list in league_list:
        count=0
        for t1 in lg_list:
            for t2 in league:
                if t1 == t2:
                    count+=1
                    if count ==4:
                        return False
    return True;            

unique_league_list = []
for i in range(len(teams)):
    league = []
    league.append(teams[i])
    for t in teams:
        if CanAddTeamLeague(t,league):
            if len(league) < 4:
                league.append(t)
        if len(league) == 4:
            if CanAddLeagueToList(league,unique_league_list):
                unique_league_list.append(league)

print(len(unique_league_list))
for l in unique_league_list:
    print(l)

# for i in teams:
#     print(i)
    
# for t in teams:
#     team_score_total.append(scores[t[0]]+scores[t[1]]+scores[t[2]]+scores[t[3]])

# fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))
# plt.plot(range(len(teams)),team_score_total)
```

This got me to wondering just how many truly unique leagues of 4 teams are possible.  I think the answer is 1715.  I switched to Java to figure this out and it took 24 seconds on my machine for the code to eliminate duplicate possibilities.  I don't think I have the math skills to calculate that with combinations/permutations (but somebody does).  Having said that, 1715 is not a huge number to deal with for brute force methods and I don't think it would take much time to calculate the stats for each team.

Here is the final piece.  I put this in another cell so you don't have to recalculate the time consuming part every time.

```
import numpy as np
scores=[7,11,20,21,22,12,13,14,15,16,23,18,19,17,24,10]

league_score_list = []
for league in unique_league_list:
    league_score=[]

    for team in league:
        team_score=0
        for ts in range(4):
            team_score += scores[team[ts]]
        league_score.append(team_score)
    league_score_list.append(league_score)            

std_list=[]
for l in league_score_list:
    std_list.append(np.std(l))

sorted_list = np.argsort(std_list)
print(league_score_list[sorted_list[0]])
print(unique_league_list[sorted_list[0]])
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: Yikes, it took some doing to get down to 1715 unique teams.  The function that takes the most time as you can imagine is CanAddLeagueToList() because of the nested for loop.  If you omit this the number only goes up to 1820.  I have to say this is much shorter than the code I wrote in Java but I still prefer Java or C# :)

Comment: Thank you David! Do you know how I would be able to sort these teams into four sets, so each team of 4 has no repetition from the pool of 16?

Comment: This forum is really supposed to be to help you troubleshoot your code.  Having said that, I already did that for you.  Did you run the code above and print the list l?  If you examine the list you will see there are no repetitions.  The the first few are [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[0, 1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[0, 1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
[[0, 1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]] so there are 1715 unique 'leagues' made up of 4 'teams' of 4 'players' w/no repetitions.

Comment: In the second part I assigned theoretical score for each player then calculated the total score for each team then calculated the standard deviation for each unique league and sorted the list so the league with the least amount of standard deviation appeared first.

Comment: If you run the second part you will see the output for, for the particular scores coded, is the follow list of team scores [66, 66, 66, 64] made up of the following team [[0, 2, 8, 14], [1, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 15]]