# Building a list of possible sentences with variable words in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to get a list of all sentence possibilities by combining sentence a list of possible sentence structures with possible variables.

```
sentenceStructures = [
  "What [x] is [y]",
  "What [y] is [x]"
]

variables = {
  "[x]": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "[y]":["q", "r", "s"]
}
```

The final answer should be

```
allPossibleSentences = [
  "What a is q",
  "What b is q",
  "What c is q",
  "What a is r",
  "What b is r",
  "What c is r",
  "What a is s",
  "What b is s",
  "What c is s",
  "What q is a",
  "What r is a",
  "What s is a",
  "What q is b",
  "What r is b",
  "What s is b",
  "What q is c",
  "What r is c",
  "What s is c"
]
```

I figure I should use recursion to get a list of all possibilities.

```
allPossibleSentences = []

def fillVariable(sentence):
    sentence.find("[")
    #this is where i'm stuck, i'm not sure how to start the recursion
    allPossibleSentences.append(possibility)

for sentence in sentenceStructures:
    fillVariables(sentence)
```

Any help or pointers appreciated?

Comment: Why not use two nested loops then?

Comment: Before writing any code, try describing the steps to solve the problem in words.

Comment: This is kind of related to a Teams building question that I answered here even though the question was downvoted.  I was bored. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087941/team-making-using-python/71096657#71096657  it's really a combinations/permutations problem right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for loop. You don't need recursion. Something along the line of

```
sentenceStructures = [
  "What [x] is [y]",
  "What [y] is [x]"
]

variables = {
  "[x]": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "[y]":["q", "r", "s"]
}

x = variables["[x]"]
y = variables["[y]"]

answer = []

for sentence in sentenceStructures:
    for x_item in x:
        for y_item in y:
            s = sentence.replace("[x]", x_item).replace("[y]", y_item)
            answer.append(s)

print(answer)
```

Comment: As an exercise for the reader: generalize the `for x_item in x:` and `for y_item in y:` to allow for any number of variables.

Comment: Good point. I took this approach because for this particular question, we needed to replace the 2 variables `[x]` and `[y]` in the input strings.